# JVM INSTR monitorenter and JVM INSTR monitorexit

Tags: java

I decompiled a source file and found some JVM instructions like JVM INSTR monitorenter and JVM INSTR monitorexit.
What does these mean?

```
public boolean isRunning()
    {
        this;
        JVM INSTR monitorenter ;
        Thread thread = _thread;
        boolean flag;
        if(thread != null)
            flag = true;
        else
            flag = false;
        this;
        JVM INSTR monitorexit ;
        return flag;
        Exception exception;
        exception;
        throw exception;
    }
```

Also what does Exception exception; , exception; and throw exception; mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`monitorenter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.monitorenter) and [`monitorexit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.monitorexit) are documented in the JVM specification, along with all the other bytecode instructions. Basically they're used to implement `synchronized` blocks and methods.

It sounds like your decompiler isn't terribly good, if it isn't able to come up with appropriate Java here... we can't tell what the `Exception` part is about when basically it's broken decompiler output. It may well correspond to something like:

```
catch(Exception exception)
{
    throw exception;
}
```

... but basically I'd find a different decompiler. (Why do you need a decompiler anyway?)

Comment: I use DJ Java Decompiler which I had personally bought, if you have any other decompiler please do recommend me - whcih can decompile the java code completely as the source code originally was.

Comment: @OsamaMohammedShaikh: What valid reason do you have for decompiling the code in the first place?

Comment: Why are you asking this to me? No one asks such questions in the first place. Its a straight forward question if you have any solid recommendations for a strong decompiler, please tell me. As I need it for decompiling a source file for my college project reference purpose.

Comment: @OsamaMohammedShaikh: It's very common to ask questions like this, actually. There are relatively few legitimate cases where decompilers are required to produce very close, compilable results. Usually if you have any legal *right* to look at the source code, you can get hold of it anyway.

Comment: Right, security researchers just get access to source code all the time.

Comment: Jon, in my case, the source code is lost.  The class file is version 46.0 (java 1.2).  It is still in production.  That being said: your comment about the "legal right to look" is troubling.  A decompiler doesn't produce the original source code: it produces a novel text document.  Users *always* have the right to use a decompiler.

Comment: @daveloyall: I suspect that depends on a lot of things - not least which country you're in.

Comment: Users *always* have the right to use a decompiler.  ...Local laws might have bugs. :)